# how to write such a regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a python regular expression which match a URL like the following rules.

1. start with "http://"
2. in the domain part, end with "some.domain"
3. in the path part, exclude end with a list of words like "tar", "zip"
4. the url may contain optional query part, like "?key1=value1&key2=value2"

For example, "http://some.domain/a.zip", "http://sub.some.domain/a.zip?key=value" matches this pattern, "http://www.other.domain/a.zip", "http://www.some.domain/a.zipp" dose not match.

Comment: Don't use a regular expression for this - use a URL parser like [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html).

Comment: Take your [pick](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex).

Comment: @Dominic Rodger, [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) is a good option, but my question is how to implement using regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, best to use a URL parser as URLs in particular can vary wildly and you could miss. However, here's one example that does what I believe you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

strings = [ 
            "http://some.domain/", 
            "http://some.domain/a.zip", 
            "http://some.domain/a.tar",
            "http://sub.some.domain/a.zip?key=value", 
            "http://www.other.domain/a.zip", 
            "http://www.some.domain/a.zipp0"
            ]

for url in strings:

    # match "http://"
    # match anything up to "some.domain/", greedy
    # match "some.domain/"
    # optionally, match anything up to .zip or .tar, greedy
    # match ".tar" or ".zip", if above optional is present
    # optionally, match a "?" after .zip/.tar, followed by anything, greedy
    # match the end of string

    if re.search(r'http://.*some\.domain/(.*\.(zip|tar)(\?.*)?)?$', url):
        print("url: {} MATCHES".format(url))
    else:
        print("url: {} DOESN'T MATCH".format(url))
```

Output:

```
./url.py
url: http://some.domain/ MATCHES
url: http://some.domain/a.zip MATCHES
url: http://some.domain/a.tar MATCHES
url: http://sub.some.domain/a.zip?key=value MATCHES
url: http://www.other.domain/a.zip DOESN'T MATCH
url: http://www.some.domain/a.zipp0 DOESN'T MATCH
```

-stevieb

Comment: hi, stevieb, I made a mistake about rule three. I want to exclude the "tar" or "zip" extension, not include! I tried add "?!" in "(zip|tar)" according documentation [re](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) to generate the regex r'http://.*some\.domain/(.*\.(?!zip|tar)(\?.*)?)?$', but it's not work

Answer (score 0):

```
^http:\/\/(?:\w+\.)?some\.domain(?:\/\w+\.(?:zip|tar))?(?:\?\w+=\w+)?$

import re
p = re.compile(ur'^http:\/\/(?:\w+\.)?some\.domain(?:\/\w+\.(?:zip|tar))?(?:\?\w+=\w+)?$', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"http://some.domain/a.zip\nhttp://sub.some.domain/a.zip?key=value\nhttp://www.other.domain/a.zip\nhttp://www.some.domain/a.zipp"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xZ6mX1/1)